# Troubleshooting JavaScript for an Order Form

Tags: javascript

I can not get the Alert Message for myFunction1() to function properly. I need it to Say Thanks for the order 'firstname' 'lastname' Your total is.....

For the total it needs to multiply the productselection value by the quantityselection value and then add the value of shippingselection value. It will then also add a 7% tax to the total. I have the following code and I can get the alert for the first message to appear like it should if your name is not inputted. However when I click order button when the name fields are filled out nothing happens? please help! Thanks!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">   <!-- links stylesheet -->
        <h1>JS Order Form</h1> <!-- Heading -->
    </head>
    <body>

    <script src="script.js"> <!--links js -->
    </script>

    <div align="center">    
    <form id="myForm">
     <fieldset>
      <legend>Personal Information:</legend>                       <!-- first Form with first and last name-->
     First Name: <input type="text" id="field1" name="fname"><br><br>
     Last Name: <input type="text" id="field2" name="lname"><br>

     </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div align="center">

    <form id="myForm1">                                                 <!-- form 2-->
     <fieldset>
      <legend>Order Info:</legend>
    <table style="width:100%">
            <table align="left">         <!-- Setting table constraints-->
            <table border="1">  
      <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Price</td>      

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Widget 1</td>            <!-- table contents-->
        <td>$5</td>     

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Widget 2</td>
        <td>$10</td>        

      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>



        Select a product:<br>
                        <select id="productselection">
                            <option value="blank"></option>
                            <option value="5">Widget 1</option>
                            <option value="10">Widget 2</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
        Select a quantitiy:<br>
                        <select id="quantityselection">
                            <option value="blank"></option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
        Select a Shipping Method:<br>
                        <select id="shippingselection">
                            <option value="blank"></option>
                            <option value="0">Standard - Free</option>
                            <option value="10">3 day - $10</option>
                            <option value="25">Next Day - $25 2</option>
                        </select>


        </div>
     </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div align="center">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction();myFunction2() ;blankElement('productselection') ;blankElement('shippingselection') ;blankElement('quantityselection');" value="Clear">     <!-- submit and clear buttons-->
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction1() ;Calculate();" value="Order">
    </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

```
function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").reset();  
    }   
    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("myForm1").reset(); 
    }

    function blankElement(id)
    {    
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.value = blank;
    }



    function myFunction1()
    {

    var f3 = document.getElementById("productselection");
      var field3 = parseInt(f3.options[f3.selectedIndex].value);
      var f4 = document.getElementById("quantityselection");
      var field4 = parseInt(f4.options[f4.selectedIndex].value);
      var f5 = document.getElementById("shippingselection");
      var field5 = parseInt(f5.options[f5.selectedIndex].value);



     var field1 = document.getElementById("field1").value.trim();
      var field1Valid= true;
     var field2 = document.getElementById("field2").value.trim();  // checks to see that a value is inputed 
    var field2Valid= true;

    if ( field1.length == 0)
     {
            field1Valid= false;
     }                                  // the following checks to see if anything is inputed and returns a true or false/yes or no
     if ( field2.length == 0)
     {
            field2Valid= false;
     }

    var formValid= field1Valid && field2Valid && field3Valid && field4Valid; //true if all fields are valid else false 
    if( !formValid){
        var alertMessage= 'Please fill in the following ';          //sets a var alert message if it meets criteria
        if( !field1Valid){ alertMessage+= '[First Name] '; }
        if( !field2Valid){ alertMessage+= '[Last Name] '; }       // adds the following fields to the alert if they did not meet criteria of being full

       alert(alertMessage);
        return false;
    }
    else{
         var alertMessage= 'Thanks for the order '+ field1+ ' '+ field2+ '. Your total is $' + (field3 * field4 + field5) + '.00.';
        alert(alertMessage);
        return true;           // pushes out alert message by using field1 and field 2 and then multipling field 3 and 4 together to get a total
    }


    }
```

Comment: what is this `element.value = blank;` what is value of 'blank` if you are trying to reset a field then try this `element.value = '';`

Comment: what are `field3Valid && field4Valid` stand for?

Answer (score 0):

`field3Valid` and `field4Valid` are not defined. either define them (and set their value) or remove them from the following line.

```
var formValid= field1Valid && field2Valid && field3Valid && field4Valid;
```

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yw2atfbo/3/) so you can see it in action.